# Facing Issues with Kubernetes High Availability cluster setup

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

I am facing issues while clustering etcd in kubernetes HA. High Availability Kubernetes Clusters. I gone through this link (http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/) . In that i have copied "etcd.yml" file  to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/"  directory in all three masters. kubelet monitoring manifests directory and created pod automatically. but etcd container is restarting continuously.

One doubt here. Assuming i have three masters and three worker nodes. inside worker nodes we are given only one active master hostname (or) ip my doubt is if active master dies how second master will take over responsibility of worker nodes. worker nodes will always look into the "first master" because we have given only one hostname in master. Here I want to know how second master will take responsibility.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [guide recommends that you put the master replicas behind a load balancer](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/#load-balancing). The details of how to do this will vary depending on the platform where you're setting up your cluster.

Comment: I am trying to set up Kubernetes HA in Oracle Virtual Box. In etcd clustering i have copied etcd.yml file to each master "/etc/kubernetes/manifests" directory. and i have changed that master ip in 3 masters now pod created automatically here etcd container getting restarted contineously iam getting below  logs

Comment: (-bash-4.2# kubectl logs etcd-server-master2
2016/03/19 21:25:46 etcd: listening for peers on http://x.x.x.x:2380
2016/03/19 21:25:46 etcd: listening for client requests on http://127.0.0.1:4001
2016/03/19 21:25:46 etcdserver: datadir is valid for the 2.0.1 format
2016/03/19 21:25:46 etcd: stopping listening for client requests on http://127.0.0.1:4001
2016/03/19 21:25:46 etcd: stopping listening for peers on http://x.x.x.x.:2380
2016/03/19 21:25:46 etcd: dial tcp: lookup discovery.etcd.io on x.x.x.x:53: server misbehaving
-bash-4.2#:) any idea please comment